# How to Check All Array Element Inside endswith()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ends-with

```js
let array1 = ["?", "!", "."];
let array2 = ["live.", "ali!", "harp", "sharp%", "armstrong","yep?"];

console.log(array2.filter((x) => x.endsWith("?")));
```

The output is just: `['yep?']`

Because the function `endsWith()` only checked for `"?"` as you see in the code.
How do I loop the elements on the `array1` (suffixes) inside the `endsWith` function so the output is:

```js
['live.', 'ali!', 'yep?']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and then [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) each element in the `filter` iteration against it.

`/[?!.]$/` says match *one* of these things in the group (`[?!.]`) before the string ends (`$`).

```js
const arr = ['live.', 'ali!', 'harp', 'sharp%', 'armstrong', 'yep?'];
const re = /[?!.]$/;

const out = arr.filter(el => el.match(re));
console.log(out);
```

Regarding your comment you can pass in a joined array to the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const query = ['.', '?', '!'];
const re = new RegExp(`[${query.join('')}]$`);

const arr = ['live.', 'ali!', 'harp', 'sharp%', 'armstrong', 'yep?'];

const out = arr.filter(el => el.match(re));
console.log(out);
```

Comment: How do you make this so you can input an array inside the regex instead? so instead of suffix... we get the strings with [ "ive." , "li!" , "ep?"]

Comment: @Royaley added a new example showing how to use an array in a regex.

Comment: Regex is so powerful oof, I can't thank you enough for this. much love bruh <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) call to loop over your `array1` and return `true` from that when you find a match instead of hardcoding the `?`:

```js
const array1 = ["?", "!", "."];
const array2 = ["live.", "ali!", "harp", "sharp%", "armstrong","yep?"];

const res = array2.filter((x) => array1.some(punc => x.endsWith(punc)));
console.log(res);
```

Above, when you return `true` (or a truthy value) from the `.some()` callback, the `.some()` method will return `true`, otherwise it will return `false` if you never return true, thus discarding it.